# Success message displaying on the wrong page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to Ajax and I am trying CRUD operations using the same. I have an **`index.php`** page where I can insert and display data, also I have links to update and delete data over there.Create, Read, Update are working fine. Now the problem is that when I click the link to Delete, I am successfully sending the id to the **`delete_back.php`** and the value is getting deleted but the success message which should be printed on the **`index.php`** as I have a div named **`#delete_msg`** over there but somehow the success message is being printed on **`delete_back.php`**.

#### index.php

```
<div id="delete_msg"></div>
```

#### select_back.php

```
    <?php
include("config.php");

$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from student");
$col=mysqli_num_fields($data);
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<$col;$i++)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";   
    }   
    echo "<td><a href='update_front.php?id=$row[0]&nm=$row[1]&add=$row[2]&cont=$row[3]'> Update </a></td>";
    echo "<td><a class='delete' href='delete_back.php?id=$row[0]'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

#### delete_back.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];

include("config.php");
$data=mysqli_query($con,"delete from student where id='$id'");
if($data=="true")
{
    echo "Data Deleted";    
}
else
{
    echo "Delete Error";    
}
?>
```

#### ajax file

```
$(".delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete_back.php",
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(msgStr){
                $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr);
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Yes Because you redirect like this `href='delete_back.php?id=$row[0]'`

Comment: url is delete_back.php but the message should be printed here  $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr);

Comment: if you give a URL in anchor tag it will redirect to that page

Comment: in that case what should be done to get the message on the index.php page? I have redirected to delete_back.php because delete code is over there.

Comment: @Nawin what does [`code`] success:function(msgStr){
                $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr); mean? Doesn't it mean that ajax is going to find this particular id and then print the success message over there?

Comment: _"somehow the success message is being printed on delete_back.php"_ - Does that mean that your ajax isn't triggered at all? Are you actually redirected to the URL `delete_back.php`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ajax is triggering just fine and the data is being deteled onlly that the success message is being displayed on delete_back.php when it should be printed on index.php as div with the id mentioned in success msg is over there.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by _"message is being displayed on delete_back.php"_. You're literally echoing that message on that page so of course it's going to be visible there.

Comment: Is this the only such table row you are creating in select_back.php, or do you have that in some kind of loop? If the latter, you created invalid HTML, by using the same ID multiple times in one document, so that would be the first thing you have to fix.

Comment: @Yuri, did but it isn't working.

Comment: When you click on "delete", what exactly happens? Do your browser redirect you to `delete_back.php` (look at the browsers address bar) or are you still on the same page? If you get redirected, then your ajax didn't get triggered. You simply deleted it through that request.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes I have created a table in a loop and have created update and delete links using the same technique but update is working just fine and results are being displayed perfectly except for delete statement. I am posting the code of select_back.php above, please check.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think you are right, ajax isn't working at all. I didn't notice initially but the page is reloading. Please tell me how to go about correcting ajax?

Comment: 1. Make sure that your JS is inside `$(function()) {  //your code  }` (or `$(document).ready(function() { //your code })`). 2. Change the event from `$("#delete").click(function(event) { ... })` to `$("body").on("click", "#delete", function(event) { ... })` and try again.

Comment: You would fix the error with the duplicate IDs ... `$("#delete")` selects the first element with such an ID in the document only, even if you have created nonsense HTML with multiple occurrences. So for all but the first such link, you did not bind any click handler at all ...

Comment: Also, you don't actually pass the `id` to your JS function, so it won't work even if it would get triggered.

Comment: @CBroe How should I select an internal link in jquery?

Comment: Oh. I didn't even see that you echoed the link in a loop.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID, and select the elements via that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have edited select_back.php, have posted the code above, plz tell me how to actually do it right?

Comment: @CBroe echo "<td><a class='delete' href='delete_back.php?id=$row[0]'>Delete</a></td>"; still not working

Comment: You have to modify `$("#delete").click()` accordingly as well, of course ...

Comment: @CBroe off course, I did that too, but still not working.

Comment: That’s most likely because you are not passing the ID of the record to delete correctly with your AJAX request ... your original code completely failed to do that at all, so have you modified it in that regard as well now …?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for helping me out, you all are great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add data-id attribute to anchor tag:

```
echo "<td><a id='delete' data-id='".$row[0]."' href='#'>Delete</a></td>";
```

You can do in your ajax be like:

```
$("#delete").click(function(event){
        var obj = $(this); // first store $(this) in obj
        var id = $(this).data('id'); // get id of data using this 
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete_back.php",
            dataType:"html",
            data: { id: id },
            type: "Post",
            success:function(msgStr){
                $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr);

        }
    })
  })
```

in your php file:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Since there is a `event.preventDefault()`, it shouldn't go to that URL either way.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Since the OP has `event.preventDefault()`, having the URL in the `href`-tag doesn't matter. Your "fix" won't solve anything. And there _should_ be an `event.preventDefault()`. The above code will actually add a `#` to the current URL.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson just add `return false;` at the end

Comment: @Yuri - Why remove it in the first place? My gut feeling is that this JS isn't even executed, and when the `delete` link is clicked, it simply redirects the user to `delete_back.php`, which would perform the delete and echo the message.

Answer (score 3):

**First of all, I really hope you don't have a loop which prints multiple anchors with same ID...**
That said, according to your html, your JS should be like the followin, otherwise you will lose your `id` value:

```
$("#delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var my_href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: my_href,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(msgStr){
                $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr);

            }
        });
        return false;
  });
```

But this isn't a really nice coding style.. I would suggest to use html5 `data-` attribute to store your `id` value

```
echo "<td><a id='delete' data-id='".$row[0]."' href='#'>Delete</a></td>";
```

You can also use `javascript:;` instead of `#` if you don't want your url to change..

And your JS should be like:

```
$("#delete").click(function(event){
        // you can avoid preventing default behaviour because your anchor doesn't have any href value
        var del_id= $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete_back.php",
            dataType:"html",
            data: {id: del_id} // use object for better reading
            success:function(msgStr){
                $("#delete_msg").html(msgStr);
            }
        });
  });
```

I also suggest you to check `.done()` construct [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: I didn't realize that I was looping the anchor with same id which is why as suggested by @CBroe, I have changed id into a class and made changes to my ajax code as well but things aint working as yet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the delete link is coming from a loop containing other delete links too. If so, this is what you should do.

```
echo '<td><a class="lnk-delete" href="#" data-id="'.$row[0].'">Delete</a></td>'; //The delete links should have 1 class name
```

Then make your ajax call

```
$('.lnk-delete').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    ajax({
        url: 'delete_back.php'
        data: {id: id},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
           $('#delete_msg').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Get the id of the item you want to delete in php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        <?php 
        //select_back.php 
        echo "<td><a id='delete' href='#'>Delete</a></td>";

        ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">


        <script>

        $("#delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var hidden_id =$("#hidden_id").val();   

        $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:"delete_back.php",
                data:"id="+hidden_id,
                success:function(data){
                 if(data.trim() == 'success')
                            {
                               $("#delete_msg").html("<div style='color:green;'>deleted successfully</div>");
                            }else{
                                //error
                            }
                        } 
            });
        });

        </script>

        <?php
        // delete_back.php

    $id=$_GET['id'];

    include("config.php");
    $data=mysqli_query($con,"delete from student where id='$id'");
    if($data)
    {
        echo "success";    
    }
    else
    {

        echo "Delete Error";    
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should write an explanation as well, not just post a bunch of code. Explain why the OP should do it this way and what error it solves.